# Error al llamar datos de un modelo en SwiftUI

Tags: swift2

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
  "Localization": {
    "Latam": "es",
    "Ingles": "en",
    "Portugues": "pt",
    "Italiano": "it"
  },
  "URL": {
    "host": "https://softguard.com/tks/public/",
    "api": "/customer/login"
  }
}
```

Y arme este struct junto a la func readFile en un swiftfile:

```
struct SoftGuardJSON : Decodable{
    var Localization : LocalizationSoft
    var URL: URLSoft
}

struct  LocalizationSoft : Decodable {
    var Latam : String
    var Ingles : String
    var Portugues : String
    var Italiano : String
}

struct URLSoft : Decodable {
    var host : String
    var api : String
}

func readFile(){
     if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestDevMobile", withExtension: "json"),
         let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
         if let softData = try? decoder.decode(SoftGuardJSON.self, from: data){
             print(softData.Localization)
             print(softData.URL)
             
         }
     }
 }
```

El JSON es leido correctamente ya que el print de la func me trae bien los datos.
Pero el inconviente que estoy teniendo es a la hora de pasar los datos al ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var softguard : SoftGuardJSON?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 4){
        Text("Acceso al centro de soporte")
                .font(.title2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

        Text("SoftGuard")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(spacing: 10 ){
                Button(action: {
                    print(softguard?.URL ?? "Error")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Idiomas")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("Ingeso")
                },
                       label: {
                    Text("Ingresar")
                })
            }
            Spacer()
        }
            .onAppear(perform: readFile)
    }
}
```

El print(softguard?.URL ?? "Error"), me imprime el error y no el url. No estoy pudiendo resolver este inconveniente de traspaso de información, donde esta el problema o como puedo resolver?

@State var softguard : SoftGuardJSON? lo puse como opcional ya que sino me tiraba el siguiente error en el App. (Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call, Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>')

Answer (score 0):

`@State var softguard : SoftGuardJSON?` nunca recibe el nuevo valor.

Solo cambia to `readFile` a...

```
func readFile(){
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestDevMobile", withExtension: "json"){
        //Usa este estilo mejor para recibir errores reales en vex de ignorar con try?
       do{
           let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           //asigna el nuevo valor a la variable
           softguard = try decoder.decode(SoftGuardJSON.self, from: data)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```